# Symfony2 spiders/bot/crawler prevention for statistics

Tags: php, symfony, caching, web-crawler

So I am trying to make some tracking services inside my controllers/twig, but I am also trying to bypass all the crawlers/spiders/bots/whatever from calling it.

In side my controller, I render a cached view if the user has already visited the page, but bots doesn't obey this rule, as they "clear" everything once they restart, so my tracking is increasing the numbers without control.

I was wondering if there are any way in order to prevent this to happen, so my stats remains stable even if my site is being crawled (which happens a lot).

I dont write here any piece of code because it is not important what it does, just a few MongoDB inserts.

This is what I do in order to cache the response if user has visited the page, and disables the cache if the item has changed (`$lastmodified`).

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge(0);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(600);
$response->setLastModified($lastmodified);
$response->headers->set('X-Cache-Type','client-no-cache');
if($response->isNotModified($request)){
    $response->setContent(304);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to archive isn't really clear. Do you want make crawlers to use cache or to prevent some statistic being gathered when the site is visited by crawlers?

Comment: I want to make crawlers to use cache, or disable the service call if I detect it is a crawler in order to prevent fake statistics

Answer (score 1):

1. I would say first of all you need to detect crawler from other users.
   I would suggest [use this approach](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-journey/magically-add-controller-args) and [this library](https://github.com/JayBizzle/Crawler-Detect) to make this. You will make a request listener and by user-agent detect if the requester is a crawler. And you will be able to inject an argument `$isCrawler` into any of your controllers. Please tell if you need more information how to do it (but it's pretty clear from links)

Something like this:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $isCrawler) {
   ....
   if (!$isCrawler) {
      $this->get('statisticService')->doSomething();
   }
}
```

2. As for cache, I think it's an unrelated topic here. But you may make crawlers to use cache. For that you need to install your own reverse proxy (for example Varnish, but even Symfony out of the box has an implementation, see [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy)).

But in this case even non-crawler users will use the cache and your statistic will miss data about it. And again you will need to make something like

```
if($response->isNotModified($request) && !$isCrawler){
    $response->setContent(304);

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you detect a crawlers/spiders? If the response is through the `User-Agent` Request Header Attribute you can use the [Restrict Route Matching through Conditions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html) as example:

<kbd>routing.yml</kbd>

```
/contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contact }
    condition: "context.getMethod() in ['GET'] and request.headers.get('User-Agent') matches '/firefox/i'"

/contact
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:contactForCrawler }
    condition: "context.getMethod() in ['GET']"
```

This example define two action's controller for the same URL: one that serve only for Firefox browser, then another for all other `User-Agent` condition.

Hope this help